# ASP.NET MVC3: Ajax postback doesnot post complete data from the view

Tags: asp.net-mvc-3, jquery

Hi Greetings for the day!

#### (1) The view model *(MyViewModel.cs)* which is bound to the view is as below...

```
public class MyViewModel
{    
   public int ParentId { get; set; }  //property1       
   List<Item> ItemList {get; set;}   //property2

   public MyViewModel()   //Constructor
   {
     ItemList=new List<Item>();  //creating an empty list of items
   }
}
```

#### (2) I am calling an action method through ajax postback *(from MyView.cshtml view)* as below..

```
function AddItem() {
    var form = $('#MyForm');
    var serializedform = form.serialize();
    $.ajax({
        type: 'POST',
        url: '@Url.Content("~/MyArea/MyController/AddItem")',
        cache: false,
        data: serializedform,
        success: function (html) {$('#MyForm').html(html);}
    });
}
```

**The below button click will call the ajax postback...**

```
<input type="button" value="Add" class="Previousbtn" onclick="AddItem()" />
```

#### (3) I have an action method in the *(MyController.cs controller)* as below...

```
public ActionResult AddItem(MyViewModel ViewModel)
{
   ViewModel.ItemList.Add(new Item());
   return View("MyView", ViewModel);
}
```

**Now the issue is, after returning from the action, there is no data in the viewmodel. But i am able to get the data on third postback !! Can you pls suggest the solution..**

> The complete form code in the view is below...

```
    @model MyViewModel

    <script type="text/javascript" language="javascript">
        function AddItem() {
            var form = $('#MyForm');
            var serializedform = form.serialize();
            $.ajax({
                type: 'POST',
                url: '@Url.Content("~/MyArea/MyController/AddItem")',
                cache: false,
                data: serializedform,
                success: function (html) {
                    $('#MyForm').html(html);
                }
            });
        }

        function RemoveItem() {
            var form = $('#MyForm');
            var serializedform = form.serialize();
            $.ajax({
                type: 'POST',
                url: '@Url.Content("~/MyArea/MyController/RemoveItem")',
                cache: false,
                data: serializedform,
                success: function (html) {
                    $('#MyForm').html(html);
                }
            });
        }

     function SaveItems() {    
        var form = $('#MyForm');
        var serializedform = forModel.serialize();
        $.ajax({
            type: 'POST',
            url: '@Url.Content("~/MyArea/MyController/SaveItems")',
            cache: false,
            data: serializedform,
            success: function (html) {
                $('#MyForm').html(html);
            }
        });
    }

    </script>
    @using (Html.BeginForm("SaveItems", "MyController", FormMethod.Post, new { id = "MyForm" }))
    {    
        @Html.HiddenFor(m => Model.ParentId)
        <div>
             <input type="button" value="Save" onclick="SaveItems()" />
        </div>
        <div>
            <table>
                <tr>
                    <td style="width: 48%;">
                        <div style="height: 500px; width: 100%; overflow: auto">
                            <table>
                                <thead>
                                    <tr>
                                        <th style="width: 80%;">
                                            Item
                                        </th>
                                        <th style="width: 10%">
                                            Select
                                        </th>
                                    </tr>
                                </thead>
                                @for (int i = 0; i < Model.ItemList.Count; i++)
                                {
                                    @Html.HiddenFor(m => Model.ItemList[i].ItemId)                                
                                    @Html.HiddenFor(m => Model.ItemList[i].ItemName)                                
                                    <tr>
                                        @if (Model.ItemList[i].ItemId > 0)
                                        {

                                            <td style="width: 80%; background-color:gray;">
                                                @Html.DisplayFor(m => Model.ItemList[i].ItemName)
                                            </td>
                                            <td style="width: 10%; background-color:gray;">
                                                <img src="@Url.Content("~/Images/tick.png")" alt="Added"/>
                                                @Html.HiddenFor(m => Model.ItemList[i].IsSelected)
                                            </td>
                                        }
                                        else
                                        {                            
                                            <td style="width: 80%;">
                                                @Html.DisplayFor(m => Model.ItemList[i].ItemName)
                                            </td>
                                            <td style="width: 10%">
                                                @if ((Model.ItemList[i].IsSelected != null) && (Model.ItemList[i].IsSelected != false))
                                                {
                                                    <img src="@Url.Content("~/Images/tick.png")" alt="Added"/>                                            
                                                }
                                                else
                                                {
                                                    @Html.CheckBoxFor(m => Model.ItemList[i].IsSelected, new { @style = "cursor:pointer" })
                                                }
                                            </td>
                                        }
                                    </tr>
                                }
                            </table>
                        </div>
                    </td>
                    <td style="width: 4%; vertical-align: middle">
                        <input type="button" value="Add" onclick="AddItem()" />
                        <input type="button" value="Remove" onclick="RemoveItem()" />
                    </td>                
                </tr>
            </table>
        </div>    
    }
```

Comment: Could you show the code of the form in the view? Also I would recommend you taking a look at the [`following article`](http://blog.stevensanderson.com/2010/01/28/editing-a-variable-length-list-aspnet-mvc-2-style/) which illustrates a nice way to achieve your goal.

Comment: Hi, I have added the code of the form in the view. Please take a look. I'm having the list of items. Each item has a name and a check box to select before adding. On clicking add button, the ajax postback is performed, and displays to the users the items which are selected for adding using an image(tick mark). There is a save button which does final saving of the selected items.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You must return PartialViewResult and then you can do something like

```
$.post('/controller/GetMyPartial',function(html){
$('elem').html(html);});

    [HttpPost]
    public PartialViewResult GetMyPartial(string id
    {


        return PartialView('view.cshtml',Model);
    }
```

Comment: No problem.  If he answer helped out, can you please vote up on this answer.  Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

In my project i get state data with country id using json like this

in my view

```
 <script type="text/javascript">
        function cascadingdropdown() {           
            var countryID = $('#countryID').val();
            $.ajax({
                url: "/City/State",
                dataType: 'json',
                data: { countryId: countryID },
                success: function (data) {
                    alert(data);
                    $("#stateID").empty();
                    $("#stateID").append("<option value='0'>--Select State--</option>");
                    $.each(data, function (index, optiondata) {
                        alert(optiondata.StateName);
                        $("#stateID").append("<option value='" + optiondata.ID + "'>" + optiondata.StateName + "</option>");
                    });
                },
                error: function () {
                    alert('Faild To Retrieve states.');
                }

            });
        } 
    </script>
```

in my controller return data in json format

```
public JsonResult State(int countryId)
        {           
            var stateList = CityRepository.GetList(countryId);
            return Json(stateList, JsonRequestBehavior.AllowGet);
        }
```

i think this will help you ....

Answer (score 0):

I resolved the issue as below...

**Issue:**

> The form code i have shown here is actually part of another view page
>   which also contains a form. So, when i saw the page source at
>   run-time, there are two form tags: one inside the other, and the
>   browser has ignored the inner form tag.

**Solution:**

> In the parent view page, earlier i had used Html.Partial to render
>   this view by passing the model to it.
>
> ```
> @using(Html.BeginForm())
> {
> ---
> ---
> @Html.Partial('/MyArea/Views/MyView',MyViewModel)
> ---
> ---
> }
> ```
>
> But now, i added a div with no content. On click of a button, i'm
>   calling an action method (through ajax postback) which then renders
>   the above shown view page *(**MyView.cshmtl**)* into this empty div.
>
> ```
>     @using(Html.BeginForm())
>     {
>     ---
>     ---
>     <div id="divMyView" style="display:none"></div>
>     ---
>     ---
>     }
> ```
>
> That action returns a separate view which is loaded into the above
>   div. Since it is a separate view with its own form tag, i'm able to
>   send and receive data on each postback.

**Thank you all for your suggestions on this :)**